# Efficient (not DataFrame.apply) way of getting cosine distance for mapped values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, cosine-similarity

Here's some data I've generated:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import scipy.spatial

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "item_1": np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=1000),
        "item_2": np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=1000),
    }
)
embeddings = {item_id: np.random.randn(100) for item_id in range(0, 10)}


def get_distance(item_1, item_2):
    arr1 = embeddings[item_1]
    arr2 = embeddings[item_2]
    return scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(arr1, arr2)
```

I'd like to apply `get_distance` to each row. I can do:

```
df.apply(lambda row: get_distance(row["item_1"], row["item_2"]), axis=1)
```

But that would be very slow for large datasets.

Is there a way to calculate the cosine similarity of the embeddings corresponding to each row, without using `DataFrame.apply`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scipy version

```
%%timeit
df.apply(lambda row: get_distance(row["item_1"], row["item_2"]), axis=1)
# 38.3 ms ± 84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

For what its worth I added numba with extra complication

Thinking about memory and numpy broadcast use tmp allocation, I used for loops

Also it is worth considering passing arguments, maybe you can pass vectors instead of dictionary.

Also first run is slow due to compilation

Also you can make it parallel with numba

```py
@nb.njit((nb.float64[:, ::100], nb.float64[:, ::100]))
def cos(a, b):
    norm_a = np.empty((a.shape[0],), dtype=np.float64)
    norm_b = np.empty((b.shape[0],), dtype=np.float64)
    cos_ab = np.empty((a.shape[0],), dtype=np.float64)

    for i in nb.prange(a.shape[0]):
        sq_norm = 0.0
        for j in range(100):
            sq_norm += a[i][j] ** 2
        norm_a[i] = sq_norm ** 0.5
    
    for i in nb.prange(b.shape[0]):
        sq_norm = 0.0
        for j in range(100):
            sq_norm += b[i][j] ** 2
        norm_b[i] = sq_norm ** 0.5
    
    for i in nb.prange(a.shape[0]):
        dot = 0.0
        for j in range(100):
            dot += a[i][j] * b[i][j]
        cos_ab[i] = 1 - dot / (norm_a[i] * norm_b[i])
    return cos_ab
```

```py
%%timeit
cos(item_1_embedded, item_2_embedded)
# 218 µs ± 1.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using vectorized `numpy` operations directly is much faster:

```py
item_1_embedded = np.array([embeddings[x]for x in df.item_1])
item_2_embedded = np.array([embeddings[x]for x in df.item_2])
cos_dist = 1 - np.sum(item_1_embedded*item_2_embedded, axis=1)/(np.linalg.norm(item_1_embedded, axis=1)*np.linalg.norm(item_2_embedded, axis=1))
```

(This version runs in `771 µs` on average on my pc, vs `37.4 ms` for the `DataFrame.apply`, which makes the pure numpy version about 50 times faster).

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize the call to `cosine` with `numpy.vectorize`. There is a slight gain in speed (34 ms vs 53 ms)

```
vec_cosine = np.vectorize(scipy.spatial.distance.cosine)
vec_cosine(df['item_1'].map(embeddings),
           df['item_2'].map(embeddings))
```

output:

```
array([0.90680875, 0.90999454, 0.99212814, 1.12455852, 1.06354469,
       0.95542037, 1.07133003, 1.07133003, 0.        , 1.00837058,
       0.        , 0.93961103, 0.8943738 , 1.04872436, 1.21171375,
       1.04621226, 0.90392229, 1.0365102 , 0.        , 0.90180297,
       0.90180297, 1.04516879, 0.94877277, 0.90180297, 0.93713404,
...
       1.17548653, 1.11700641, 0.97926805, 0.8943738 , 0.93961103,
       1.21171375, 0.91817959, 0.91817959, 1.04674315, 0.88210679,
       1.11806218, 1.07816675, 1.00837058, 1.12455852, 1.04516879,
       0.93713404, 0.93713404, 0.95542037, 0.93876964, 0.91817959])
```

Comment: The docs read "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop." so I'm not sure this'll scale

Comment: I know @ignoring_gravity, I provided the numbers, there is a slight gain, not revolutionary ;)